# I want to create a model for this JSON data in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, loopbackjs, loopback

```
 "US Virgin Islands": [
"Charlotte Amalie",
"Christiansted",
"Frederiksted",
"Kingshill",
"St John Island"
],
```

I have this JSON file.  I want to save the data as it is.  So country name and all the cities it has.  I have created a collection called address but I don't know how to set the properties correctly. I am using MongoDB as database.  I want to create the json Model.

```
 "name": "address",
  "base": "PersistedModel",

  "idInjection": true,
"options": {
"validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
 "country": {
   "type": "object",
   "required": true
}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use related model in your Address model you need to use relation. I recommend to use loopback cli to do it. Also, check [relations](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Define-model-relations.html) chapter in loopback docs to get more informations about relations.

Assuming you have the **country** model, the **address** model would be defined as:

```
{
   "name":"address",
   "base":"PersistedModel",
   "idInjection":true,
   "options":{
      "validateUpsert":true
   },
   "relation": {
      "country": {
         "type": "hasOne",
         "model": "country"
         "foreignKey": ""
      }
   }
}
```

Additionally, you need to create a belongsTo relation in the address model:

```
{
   "name":"country",
   "base":"PersistedModel",
   "idInjection":true,
   "options":{
      "validateUpsert":true
   },
   "properties": { ... }
   "relation": {
      "address": {
         "type": "belongsTo",
         "model": "address"
         "foreignKey": ""
      }
   }
}
```

It will create a field `countryId` in your **address** model automatically. Then, if you would like to load the address with the whole country model instance instead of just `countryId`, you would need to call something like:

```
Address.find({where: {id: someId}, include: 'country'})
```